# I am trying to import data from excel into MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel

1. I have created a small excel file to try this process

```
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ | Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ | S no     | int(11)     | NO   | PI | NULL    |       | | Order    | int(11)  
    | YES  |     | NULL    |       | | Price    | int(11)     | YES  |  
    | NULL    |       | | comments | var char(45) | YES  |     | NULL   
    |       |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ 4 rows in set (1.21 sec)
```

This is the code I am using in python for the same

```
import xlrd import pymysql book =
xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\excel-python-mysql.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Connect to the database 
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='*****',
                                 db='trial',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) 
cursor = connection.cursor() 
query = """INSERT INTO demo(Sno,Order,Price,Comments)VALUES(%d,%d,%d,%s)"""  
for r in range(1,sheet.nrows):
    Sno = sheet.cell(r,0).value  
    Order = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    Price = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    Comments = sheet.cell(r,3).value
    values = (Sno,Order,Price,Comments)
    cursor.execute(query,values)

cursor.close()
connection.commit()

connection.close()
```

but I am facing error stating "%d format: a number is required, not str" I want to move the data to MySQL for further use it at Metabase.

Comment: the error is because your excel file is storing number as string, try to edit %d to %s where ever required.

Comment: Hi i tried that too then i got this error ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order,Price,Comments)VALUES(1,2,40,'Yes')' at line 1")

Comment: INSERT INTO demo(Sno,Order,Price,Comments) VALUES(%d,%d,%d,%s), guess there is a space missing in your query,

Comment: Try using `%s` as placeholder, regardless of the parameter's data type. The code [suggests this](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/cursors.py#L155) for `args` being a list or tuple. Query string placeholders are not to be confused with those in Python's string formatting.